# GWT. Prevent user from opening Disclosure panel

Tags: java, gwt

How to prevent user from opening Disclosure panel? I want to open and close it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `disclosurePanel.setOpen(true/false);`

See [api](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html)

But I think not allowing the user to open / close the panel himself is rather bad practice and not user friendly, as the user expects to be able to open it.

Comment: ...Maybe it would be better to have SimplePanel and hide/unhide it programmatically.

Comment: Oh, is that what you are trying to achieve, @Hello? Not show something to the user at all (because he has not sufficient rights or similar reasons)? If that is the case, I agree with Piotrek, hide the panel completely. With a closed disclosure panel, the user still know that something is there